# Preferred way of #! in shell scripts

Tags: shell

I searched google but couldn't find an answer to this rather simple question. I have a python script that has the hash-bang (#!) on the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

However, what if this is run on a computer with python in /bin/python or /usr/local/bin/python, or some other place? There has to be a better way to set the interpreter for a shell script. It should be possible to set it via $PATH, as that will know where to find python if it's installed on the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use env.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

It's not bulletproof, but it covers more cases than /usr/bin/python.

Comment: I did not know env did that!  But, this is a minor security risk -- a malicious user may place their own binary code in ./python and execute actions as the target user whenever a user who has "." in their $PATH runs a Python script with this hash-bang line.

Comment: Searching PATH for your binaries is normal. The problem in your scenario is that the user has "." in their path, not that they are using the shell builtins PATH to run commands.

Comment: @Phil: In principle I agree that the problem is with the $PATH, but in practice, if users commonly make this mistake then it's to some extent irresponsible to ignore it.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's just simply incorrect. The fundamental problem with the situation you describe is that the user has "." in their PATH. That opens up security vulnerabilities. What you're saying is that we should never run commands without using the full path, use system libraries etc. etc.

Comment: In a world of ideal security, that's right, you wouldn't use $PATH at all -- but in the real world $PATH's just too convenient to pass up.  Interesting that you mention system libraries -- $LD_LIBRARY_PATH has been a notorious rootkit attack vector.

Comment: Your comment was meant to highlight a security risk in what I've posted. The security risk is not directly related to the answer, it's related to the shell environment in which situation means running any command could potentially cause a security risk, hence it's irrelevance.

Comment: No.  Suppose the script is a CGI script or will be run as a cron job.  "#!/usr/bin/env python" creates a (minor) security risk; "#!/usr/bin/python" does not.  I say "minor" because an attacker can only gain the privileges of the user running the script, not root.

Comment: That is akin to saying that a particular car has poor security, because if you leave the window open, someone can steal your belongings. This is where I bow out, we're going around in circles.

Comment: Yes that's a pretty good analogy!  I would say that a car with windows that can't be wound down is more secure (though a pain to use).  Anyway, "." in $PATH is not something I lose sleep over, I'll be using your env trick in future.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

`env` is virtually always in `/usr/bin`, and will execute any program in the `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

Some people prefer to start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Not sure that this is a vast improvement as you're now assuming that python is in the path and that it's the right version, but it's an option.